# Change size of specific font

Tags: javascript, webfonts

Assume there are two languages (English and Chinese) in a web page. I need to increase size of  Chinese font on my web page. i don't need to change size of English fonts. only need to increase size of Chinese fonts. How could i do this ? are there any way to do this using java script or any other technology ?

Comment: Is your Chinese content wrapped in any specific tag/class combination?

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on @MichaelRobinson's comment:

You should have the text marked up by using the [`lang` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/dirlang.html#adef-lang) and then you can use the CSS [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors) (particularly the hyphen-separated variant) or the [`:lang` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#lang) to select those texts, e.g.:

```
[lang|=en] {
   font-size: 12px;
}

:lang(zh) {
   font-size: 15px;
}

<h1 lang="en">English</h1>
<p lang="zh">汉语</lang>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not test it, but I suspect the following will work if the font families are different. Using query you can retrieve css values of an element. If you retrieve the font-family value, you should have the font name. Based on that you can determine if this element has a chinese or an english font. If the font-family is the chinese fonts, you can set font-size to be bigger.